# Rotating the 3d object with the blueprint background

Tags: after-effects

I have some 3d objects that I want to show using After Effects.

With these objects I can create various types of extensions, like: IGS, SAT, OBJ, STL, ...

I would just like to rotate them on the screen with a blueprint background, as in the figure below:

[image]

With blue background and with grids.

The object need not be solid, just highlight the outline as in the image...

I searched for something on the internet, but found nothing.

I do not need an explanation. If someboby find any link where I can learn the technique would be very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this video does not appear as create showing only the outline, but it is already possible to have an idea of how to import the 3d object.

[How To Import 3D Model In After Effects CS5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5hkUhQ1sU4)

Comment: Could you briefly describe the steps in the video in case it becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

In the video I found you should model using 3dStudioMax or other of the genre.

[How to Import 3d Model in After Effects CC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLsZr84AI1s)